# reading blanks as NAN - R

Tags: r, csv, nan, data-conversion

I imported my `df` from `python` to `.csv` and then to `r`, and `r` reads the blank values in the `.csv` (which are `NaN` in `python`) as blank cells. I need that r read those blanks as missing values. How can I do that?

In addition, if I do `sum(is.na(df))` it gives me 9 `NaN`. When, in `python`, it had `3545 NaN` values. Why happens this?

PS: I don't have blank cells in my initial dataframe, so I could just do

```
isblank(df) <- NaN               # But I invented this command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we read the dataset, there is an option to specify the `NA` elements with `na.strings`

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = c('NaN', ''))
```

Now, we can check with `is.na`

---

If we are continuing the original approach, there is an option to check for `NaN` with `is.nan`, but it can only check on `vector`s or columns of dataset

```
sum(sapply(df, is.nan))
```